# Basic Adding - Expression was too complex error (Swift)

Tags: swift

Trying to add some simple numbers together. Get the "Expression was too complex to be solved in a reasonable time..." error on the final line. Why? Surely it can't come much simpler?

```
    let year   = calendar.component(.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: inputGregorianDate)
    let month  = calendar.component(.CalendarUnitMonth, fromDate: inputGregorianDate)  
    let day    = calendar.component(.CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: inputGregorianDate)

    // Conversion Calulation
    let AGR = year/100
    let BGR = AGR/4
    let CGR = 2 - AGR + BGR
    var EGR = 0.00
    if (month <= 2 ) {
        EGR = 365.25 * Double(year + 4716)
    } else {
        EGR = 365.25 * Double(year + 4716);
    }
    let FGR = 30.6001 * Double(month + 1);
    let dateJulian = Double(CGR + day + EGR + FGR - 1524.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Conversion Calulation
let AGR = Double(year) / 100
let BGR = AGR / 4.0
let CGR = 2.0 - AGR + BGR
var EGR = 0.0

// this conditional doesn't make any sense
if (month <= 2 ) {
    EGR = 365.25 * Double(year + 4716)
} else {
    EGR = 365.25 * Double(year + 4716)
}

let FGR = 30.6001 * Double(month + 1)
let dateJulian = CGR + Double(day) + EGR + FGR - 1524.5
```

Comment: Yes and thank you - but why isn't the compiler giving a Double/Int/Int32 conversion error instead? Many thanks, I'll tie these down at source in future.

Comment: @EdwardHasted Swift is well known for the miss leading error messages